# How to change settings in a PowerPoint theme?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I have a **.pptx** presentation that contains a specific theme named ModernPortfolio.

In this theme are defined some settings, such as the:

- Font Type
- Font Color
- Fixed Structure of some slides (for example I have a slide where the model defines fixed non-exchangeable images and under this image a text area)

What can I do to change these settings?

Answer (score 1):

***PowerPoint 2010:***

Change Font Colour:

- Select your theme.
- Click the Design Tab > Colours (in themes group) > Create new Theme Colors
- Change your colors.
- Click save

Change Fonts:

- Select your theme.
- Click the Design Tab > Fonts (in themes group) > Create New Theme Fonts
- Change your colors.
- Click save

***PowerPoint 2013:***

Change Font Colour:

- Select your theme
- Click the Design tab > Click the arrow in the variants tab > Click Colors > Customize colors
- Change your colors
- Click save

Change Fonts:

- Select your theme
- Click the Design tab > Click the arrow in the variants tab > Click Fonts > Customize Fonts
- Change your fonts
- Click save

For your last thing:

> ...fixed structure of some slides (for example I have a slide where the model defines a fixed non-exchangeable images and under this image a text area)

I think what you want to do is change the Slide Master. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Look [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/edit-a-slide-master-HP005194498.aspx) for details on how to change the slide master.